# Inserting new numbered lines into existing text document using bash

Tags: bash

I have a document resembling this format (with many more lines):

```
abc
def
hij
klm
nop
```

I need the output file to look like this:

```
>1
abc
>2
def
>3
hij
>4
klm
>5
nop
```

Basically, inserting a header with a number count before the start of each existing line. I've been experimenting using the sed command but so far without any success. Can anybody offer a suggestion on how to achieve this using Bash?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: So far the closest I've got is with using `sed -i '1 i\>1' myfile.txt`. I then attempted to make '1' into a variable that increments in a loop but I'm just getting errors

Comment: `sed = myfile.txt | sed '1~2s/.*/>&/'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution with `awk`

```
$ awk '{print ">"NR "\n"$0}' 1.txt
>1
abc
>2
def
>3
hij
>4
klm
>5
nop
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simple and readable solution**:
Iterate, increment, output.

Storing output in a file called `output.txt`:

```
header=1                           #Header is num to insert
for item in `cat lines.txt`;       #loop through your other file
do
        echo $header >> output.txt #Insert header
        echo $item >> output.txt   #Insert line from file
        header=$((header+1))       #Increment the header
done
```

Gives you an output that looks like:

```
$cat output.txt
1
egg
2
steak
3
cheese
4
chicken
5
asparagus
```

**Still Simple, slightly less readable solution:**

```
header=1
for item in `cat lines.txt`;
do
        echo -e "$header\n$item" >> output.txt #Use echo -e to interpret newline character.
        header=$((header+1))
done
```

Gives the same output:

```
  $cat output.txt
    1
    egg
    2
    steak
    3
    cheese
    4
    chicken
    5
    asparagus
```

Comment: [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor), and don't use `echo` with content you don't control. Look at what happens with your code if you have a line that contains `*`, for example -- or one with a literal string like `\t` (two characters, a backslash and then a `t`). Re: `echo`, see the APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections of [the POSIX spec for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html), which explicitly advises using `printf` instead.

Comment: `header=1; while IFS= read -r item; do printf '%s\n' "$header" "$item"; (( ++header )); done <lines.txt >output.txt` -- more efficient since it only opens `output.txt` once instead of re-opening it every time you want to write just one line, and it won't mangle escape sequences in your text.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This code also achieves what I needed to do.

Answer (score 0):

Using `nl`, *number lines of files*:

```
$ nl -s $'\n' -w 1 file
1
abc
2
def
3
hij
4
klm
5
nop
```

`man nl`:

```
-s, --number-separator=STRING
       add STRING after (possible) line number

-w, --number-width=NUMBER
       use NUMBER columns for line numbers
```